# Why/how are division and multiplication equally fast here?

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point

I'm trying to make a simple benchmarking algorithm, to compare different operations. Before I moved on to the actual functions i wanted to check a trivial case with a well-documented outcome : multiplication vs. division.

Division should lose by a fair margin from the literature i have read. When I compiled and ran the algorithm the times were just about 0. I added an accumulator that is printed to make sure the operations are actually carried out and tried again. Then i changed the loop, the numbers, shuffled and more. All in order to prevent any and all things that could cause "divide" to do anything but floating point division. To no avail. The times are still basically equal.

At this point I don't see where it could weasel its way out of the floating point divide and I give up. It wins. But I am really curious why the times are so close, what caveats/bugs i missed, and how to fix them.

(I know filling the vector with random data and then shuffling is redundant but I wanted to make sure the data was accessed and not just initialized before the loop.)

("String compares are evil", i am aware. If it is the cause of the equal times, i will gladly join the witch hunt. If not, please don't mention it.)

compile:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cc
```

tests:

```
./a.out multiply
2.42202e+09
1000000
t1 = 1.52422e+09    t2 = 1.52422e+09
difference = 0.218529
Average length of function : 2.18529e-07 seconds 

./a.out divide
2.56147e+06
1000000
t1 = 1.52422e+09    t2 = 1.52422e+09
difference = 0.242061
Average length of function : 2.42061e-07 seconds
```

the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <random>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

double get_time()
{
    struct timeval t;
    struct timezone tzp;
    gettimeofday(&t, &tzp);
    return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}

double multiply(double lhs, double rhs){
    return lhs * rhs;
}


double divide(double lhs, double rhs){
    return lhs / rhs;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1)
        return 0;
    double grounder = 0; //prevent optimizations

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(1.0, 100.0);

    size_t loop1 = argc > 2 ? std::stoi (argv[2]) : 1000;
    size_t loop2 = argc > 3 ? std::stoi (argv[3]) : 1000;

    std::vector<size_t>vecL1(loop1);
    std::generate(vecL1.begin(), vecL1.end(), [generator, distribution] () mutable { return distribution(generator); });

    std::vector<size_t>vecL2(loop2);
    std::generate(vecL2.begin(), vecL2.end(), [generator, distribution] () mutable { return distribution(generator); });

    double (*fp)(double, double);
    std::string function(argv[1]);
    if (function == "multiply")
        fp = (*multiply);
    if (function == "divide")
        fp = (*divide);

    std::random_shuffle(vecL1.begin(), vecL1.end());
    std::random_shuffle(vecL2.begin(), vecL2.end());

    double t1 = get_time();
    for (auto outer = vecL1.begin(); outer != vecL1.end(); outer++)
        for (auto inner = vecL2.begin(); inner != vecL2.end(); inner++)
            grounder += (*fp)(*inner, *outer);

    double t2 = get_time();
    std::cout << grounder << '\n';
    std::cout << (loop1 * loop2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "t1 = " << t1 << "\tt2 = " << t2 
        << "\ndifference = " << (t2 - t1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average length of function : " << (t2 - t1) * 1/(loop1 * loop2) << " seconds \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should run your entire loop, say, a million times for this to be a meaningful comparison.

Comment: What's the assembly generated for the `multiply` and `divide` functions? You've set up quite a nice test case here, but I think the overhead will be in the loops and the function calls.

Comment: Without comment on whether the method of measuring is correct, don't the results you get show division as 10% slower than multiplication? Did you miss that, or were you simply expecting the difference to be bigger?

Comment: Check following [document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)  and find how many clock cycles it takes on your CPU to execute FMUL and FDIV instructions. For instance on Sandy Bridge FMUL = 5 cycles, FDIV = 10-24 (depend on precision). So multiplication is at least 2 times faster.

Comment: @hvd Those results are not consistent. The result times are always around 2e-07 seconds but i have seen the divide be 5-10 percent faster than multiply in back-to-back tests. I just wanted to give my results so people had some idea of what the results were and could immediately see "multiply nor divide should take that long, you measure something else".

Comment: How do you reliably measure 2e-7 seconds on, say, a PC or Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't just measuring the speed of multiplication/divide. If you put your code into https://godbolt.org/ you can see the assembly generated.

You are measuring the speed of calling a function and then doing multiply/divide inside the function. The time taken for the single multiply/divide instruction is tiny compared to the cost of the function calls so gets lost in the noise. If you move your loop to inside your function you'll probably see more of a difference. Note that with the loop inside your function your compiler may decide to vectorise your code which will still show whether there is a difference between multiply and divide but it wont be measuring the difference for the single mul/div instruction.